# Save Raster Layer as PNG using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis

Using the QGIS application, I am able to do this.
However, I am unsure of how to do it using Python.

I have this so far:

```
from qgis.gui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from qgis.core import *
import time
import sys

def main():
    qgis_prefix="/usr"    
    QgsApplication.setPrefixPath(qgis_prefix, True) 
    app = QgsApplication([], True)
    app.initQgis()

    canvas = QgsMapCanvas()
    canvas.setCanvasColor(Qt.white)

    fileName = "/..."
    fileInfo = QFileInfo(fileName)
    baseName = fileInfo.baseName()
    path = fileInfo.filePath()
    rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(path, baseName)
    if not rlayer.isValid():
            print "Layer is not valid!"
    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(rlayer)
    canvas.setExtent(rlayer.extent())
    canvas.setLayerSet([QgsMapCanvasLayer(rlayer)])

    canvas.refresh()
    app.exec_()
    app.exitQgis()
main()
```

Also, I can't get this program to terminate without manually doing it.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following line after `canvas.setLayerSet([QgsMapCanvasLayer(rlayer)])` to save the canvas as a png file:

```
canvas.saveAsImage("path/to/image.png")
```

You can also try closing the application using `sys.exit()`.

---

So your code could look like:

```
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.core import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import sys, time

def main():
    qgis_prefix="/usr"    
    QgsApplication.setPrefixPath(qgis_prefix, True) 
    app = QgsApplication([], True)
    app.initQgis()

    canvas = QgsMapCanvas()
    canvas.setCanvasColor(Qt.white)

    fileName = "/..."
    fileInfo = QFileInfo(fileName)
    baseName = fileInfo.baseName()
    path = fileInfo.filePath()
    rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(path, baseName)
    if not rlayer.isValid():
        print "Layer is not valid!"
    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(rlayer)
    canvas.setExtent(rlayer.extent())
    canvas.setLayerSet([QgsMapCanvasLayer(rlayer)])
    # Save canvas as image
    canvas.saveAsImage("path/to/image.png")

    canvas.refresh()
    app.exec_()
    app.exitQgis()
    sys.exit()    
main()
```